# How to indent text without using margin or padding in html code?

Tags: html, css

Text inside the `p` should start in the same line with the `h3` element just like in the image bellow, but without using `margin` or `padding`. Any solution for this?

[image]

```css
.inner h1, h3{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <h1>1.</h1> <h3>Download app</h3> <h3>Free</h3>
  <p> Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
  <p> Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use paragraph instead of heading,and set style separately.

Comment: `<h1>1.</h1><h3>Download app</h3>` breaks my heart. I would rather do `<h1><span>1.</span>Header</h1>` or maybe even use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F3Bcd/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use `ol` list for this :

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h3>Download app<br/>Free</h3>
    <p> Some text here Some text here Some text here<br/>Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `flex-box` you can "stretch" the `h1` to take the entire height of the right side.

```css
.inner {
  display: flex;
}

h1,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <h1>1.</h1>
  <div>
    <h3>Download app Free</h3>
    <p> Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
    <p> Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `text-indent` to `p` tag like this:

```
.inner p {
  text-indent: 23px;
}
```

```css
.inner h1, h3{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner p {
  text-indent: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <h1>1.</h1><h3> Download app</h3> <h3>Free</h3>
  <p> Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
  <p> Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
</div>
```